# Dividing a circle into 12 equal parts using OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, photogrammetry

I have this image
[image: Target]

Using Hough Transform, I am drawing circles on the target, here is the code and the result

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math

bgr_img = cv2.imread('16-Bit_ID-00001.jpg') # read as it is

if bgr_img.shape[-1] == 3:           # color image
    b,g,r = cv2.split(bgr_img)       # get b,g,r
    rgb_img = cv2.merge([r,g,b])     # switch it to rgb
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
else:
    gray_img = bgr_img

img = cv2.medianBlur(gray_img, 95)     # blur value acts as a filter
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,30,
                            param1=50,param2=50,minRadius=60,maxRadius=0)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
    #sliceno = np.int32((math.pi + np.arctan2(Y, X)) * (N / (2 * math.pi)))

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(rgb_img)
plt.title('Input Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(cimg)
plt.title('Hough Transform'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

The result I get is 
[image: Result of Hough Transform]

Now I want to divide the circle made by the hough transform into 12 equal parts. 
Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by divide - create lines dividing circle in 12 or make 12 different objects using circle ?

Comment: 12 different objects using circle, this one

Comment: Would be splitting the circle in 12 equal sections to the determine the location of the right hand side extrusion (a bit like a clock handle / settings knob ?) Also out of curiosity, what's does the image represent ? (it looks interesting)

Comment: It is a coded target made using binary numbers. The right hand side extrusion has the code, so when we split the circle into 12 equal parts, we then write binary code of each 12 parts. it will be like the arc which comes over the right hand side extrusion will get 1 and the arcs on the black area will get 0. we will get some thing as (01111000000)

Comment: George Profenza
Do you know how to split the circle into 12 equal parts?

Answer (score 0):

I did an attempt but it is far from perfect and not what I wanted to do but still here it is

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math

bgr_img = cv2.imread('16-Bit_ID-00001.jpg') # read as it is

if bgr_img.shape[-1] == 3:           # color image
    b,g,r = cv2.split(bgr_img)       # get b,g,r
    rgb_img = cv2.merge([r,g,b])     # switch it to rgb
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
else:
    gray_img = bgr_img

img = cv2.medianBlur(gray_img, 95)     # blur value acts as a filter
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,30,
                            param1=50,param2=50,minRadius=60,maxRadius=0)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
angle = 0
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
 cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
 cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
    # dividing the circle into 12 equal parts
 (x, y), radius = (i[0],i[1]),i[2]

 radius = int(radius)
 angle = angle +30
 x_2 = int(round(x + radius * math.cos(angle * math.pi / 180.0)));
 y_2 = int(round(y + radius * math.sin(angle * math.pi / 180.0)));



 cv2.line(cimg, (i[0],i[1]),(x_2,y_2),(255,127,0),3,cv2.LINE_AA)
 angle = angle +30
 x_2 = int(round(x + radius * math.cos(angle * math.pi / 180.0)));
 y_2 = int(round(y + radius * math.sin(angle * math.pi / 180.0)));



 cv2.line(cimg, (i[0],i[1]),(x_2,y_2),(255,127,0),3,cv2.LINE_AA)

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(rgb_img)
plt.title('Input Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(cimg)
plt.title('Hough Transform'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

and here is the result
[image: Result]